# GO - find event by time between 2 timestamps

Tags: database, go, scripting, nextcloud

i have an event that has 3 values: time of start, time of end and summary

I need to find an event , where current timestamp is between time of start and time of end

I solved this with this piece of code, but i am not really sure how good it is, because it just converts time to int and then ififif.
I wanted to ask if anyone knows any better solution

```
if(intdtstart < inttime){
                if(intdtend > inttime){
                    fmt.Println("inttime ",inttime,"intdtstart ",intdtstart,"intdtend ",intdtend)
                    fmt.Println(summary)
                }
```

Comment: Use [`now.Before(end)`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before) and [`now.After(start)`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After).

Comment: example: https://play.golang.org/p/N3uNZlfFnAI